# sharepoint 2010 browser compatibility issue

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I used bootsrap and rest api in sharepoint 2010.it works in chrome and firefox.but not work in IE.i updated browser compatibility  in my page as well as masterpage..still not working..can anyone give me the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to update Document Mode meta tag in your master page to IE-11:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but i tried this one not working